Which IC is this marked as ATMLH2392DCM?
What is this IC (please see the image) number is ATMLH2392DCM TH 223900Y?


Atmel AT24C128C.
Data sheet says it has a product code of 2DC and the M is the voltage range specification.

So is it surely a memory chip?

@Meet Yes it definitely is.
